# formula for index of a children of a node in a d-ary heap

Tags: algorithm, heap

Assume we have a d-ary heap and we index the nodes from top to bottom and from left to right(starting with 1). Then the children from node i are the nodes with index d*i,...,d*i+(d-1). I read this formula in a couple of books but in none of them were an explanation why these formulas are true. Maybe I am overlooking something but is it really that clear that these formulas are true?

Comment: What makes you think it is not true?

Comment: i don't think they are wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's really that clear if you understand how a d-ary heap is stored in an array. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/10/05/the-d-ary-heap/ for a little more explanation.

Comment: If it is so clear than why didn't your note that the formula is wrong as stated above?

Comment: But the formula above is correct. The index of the first child is `d*i`, and the last child is `(d*i)+(d-1)`. So in a 3-ary tree, the first child of the root is `(3*1)`, and the last child is `(3*1)+(3-1)`.

Comment: no. The index of the first child is 2 not 3.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I generalized from the binary tree formula, forgetting that you said the root is at 1. Yet another reason I think starting at 1 is a bad idea.

Comment: The formula just happens to have this nice form if you start indexing with 1 otherwise you will get the formula given in Gribouillis answer. Nevertheless one can obviously use the same derivation in both cases. Maybe it is not clear what I am asking. I know that I can draw an example and heuristically derive these equations. But this is not a proof, nor is it to prove the formula for d = 2 and then substituting other values of d(although this might be true if the proof for d = 2 generalizes nicely which is very likely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find `d * i + 2 - d` for the  index of the first child, if items
are numbered starting from 1. Here is the reasoning

Each row contains the children of the previous row. If `n[r]` are
the number of items on row `r`, one must have `n[r+1] = d * n[r]`, which
proves that `n[r] = d**r` if the first row is numbered `0`. The index
of the first item of row `r` is `f[r] = 1 + (d**r - 1)/(d - 1)` by the sum
of geometric sequences. If item X with number `i` is on row `r`, let's write
`i = f[r] + k` with `0 <= k < d**r`. There are `k` items on the row before X,
hence there are `d * k` items before X's first child on row r+1. The
index of X's first child is `f[r+1] + d * k = f[r+1] + d * (i - f[r])`
The calculus gives `d * i + 2 - d` for the index of the first child.

Actually, if we start numbering the items from 0 instead of 1, the formula becomes simply `d * i + 1` for the index of the first child, and this can be easily proven by induction because the index of the first child of item `i+1` is obtained by adding `d`, but `(d * i + 1) + d = d * (i + 1) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this diagram will help, at least for d=2:

```
 1
 2                       3
 4           5           6           7
 8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: It was useful for seeing the relationship of the nodes in a tree, but it could use a little more explanation to accompany the diagram. "Here's a picture" doesn't convey as much value as "Here's why this picture is useful." I was trying to figure out this relationship with a 0-indexed list, so seeing it as 1-indexed instantly conveyed what I needed to know, but it might have been better to relate it back to the question.